# A Problem on Schrodinger's Equation and wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

**QUESTION:**

> Let $\Psi(x,t) = F(x).G(t)$ be a solution of the time-dependent S.E. Then show that $F(x)$ satisfies the time-independent S.E.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

The time-dependent S.E is given by:

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\frac{\partial ^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} + V\Psi$$

Substituting $\Psi = F(x).G(t)$ we have:
$$i\hbar\frac{dG}{dt}F(x) = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 F}{dx^2}G(t) + VF(x)G(t)\tag1$$

This dosen't seem to help very much. How is it evident that $F(x)$ must satisfy:

$$EF(x) = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\frac{\partial ^2 F(x)}{\partial x^2} + VF(x)$$ if it satisfies (1)? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: divide both sides of 1) by $\Psi$ and try to understand when this new equation can be true given that $x$ and $t$ are independent.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a procedure used all the time when solving partial differential equations by separation of variables.

You did it all right, equation $(1)$ is in fact correct. Now divide the equation by $\Psi(x,t)=F(x)G(t)$ and you'll find that

$$i\hbar \dfrac{1}{G(t)}\dfrac{dG}{dt}=-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{1}{F(x)}\dfrac{d^2F}{dx^2}+V(x)$$

Now observe that the left side depends just on $t$ and the right side depends just on $x$. The only way this can be true is if they are actually constant. This is the important argument, so think of it a little bit and convince yourself.

With this procedure you end up with 2 equations. Let's call the constant $E$, then

$$i\hbar\dfrac{1}{G(t)}\dfrac{dG}{dt}=E$$

$$-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{1}{F(x)}\dfrac{d^2 F}{dx^2}+V(x)=E$$

Now multiply the second equation by $F(x)$ and you find that it satisfies the time-independent Schrödinger equation

$$-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2F}{dx^2}+V(x)F(x)=EF(x).$$

The usual procedure when trying to solve via separation of variables is this: (i) suppose the solution is separable, (ii) substitute the separable form on the equation, (iii) decouple the dependencies usually by dividing by the function in separable form, (iv) isolate each dependency on its own side, (v) recognize both sides must be some constant, (vi) turn the initial equation into two equations in less variables, and if some of the equations contain more than one variable, repeat the process to isolate the dependencies again.